# Increase Number of Executors for a spark instance

Tags: apache-spark

I am launching a spark instance via pyspark. The system I am using is r3.8x on EC2 with 244gb ram and 32 vCPU. The code I am using is

```
#Import Packages
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import shutil

#Initialize Spark Environment
spark_path = "C:\spark"
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_path
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = spark_path

sys.path.append(spark_path + "/bin")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/pyspark/")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib/pyspark.zip")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip")

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

sc =  SparkContext("local", "test") 
#sc =  SparkContext("local", "test") 

sc.defaultParallelism
1
```

I have set a few parameters using spark-defaults.conf file as follows

```
spark.driver.memory 20g
spark.executor.cores 2
spark.executor.instances 16
spark.executor.memory 220g
spark.memory.fraction 0.07
spark.worker.cleanup.enabled true
```

This is confirmed from this code in pyspark

```
> sc._conf.getAll()
[('spark.executor.memory', '220g'),
 ('spark.app.id', 'local-1500885816084'),
 ('spark.app.name', 'test'),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.driver.port', '61076'),
 ('spark.executor.instances', '16'),
 ('spark.executor.cores', '2'),
 ('spark.master', 'local[32]'),
 ('spark.driver.memory', '20g'),
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
 ('spark.memory.fraction', '0.07'),
 ('spark.worker.cleanup.enabled', 'true')]
```

Now when I check my resource manager using localhost:4041 I get this table

[image]

It seems as if only one executor is running. How can I set this up right?

Comment: What @pierre told is correct, but   spark.memory.fraction 0.07 is very less.
Thats the reason for 1.3gigs storage memory(cache and execution). The 0.75 is recomended

Answer (score 2):

The spark.master is set to `local[32]` which will start a single jvm driver with an embedded executor (here with 32 threads).

In local mode, `spark.executor.cores` and `spark.executor.instances` do not apply.

You should look at running in standalone mode where you will be able to have a driver and distinct executors.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

On a side note, the current config will request 16 executor with 220GB each, this cannot be answered with the spec you have given.